# Dynamic link is not cleared after retrieving

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, firebase-dynamic-links

In my flutter app I'm using the [firebase dynamic links plugin](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/firebase_dynamic_links).

In the main function the `retrieveDynamicLink` is called and the link is handled, as well as every time the app is resumed a lifecycle listener calls `retrieveDynamicLink` again and handles the link.

The plugin calls the android method: `getDynamicLink(registrar.activity().getIntent())`, and the documentation states that this method should clean the intent to make any other call return null until the app is open/resumed from another link.

But that's not what is happening, not always at least.

If I open the app from a dynamic link, switch to another app, and then go back to the app, the `retrieveDynamicLink` call returns the link again.
If I originally open the app from its icon that does not happen.

Does anyone have any suggestion?

I'm using `firebase_dynamic_links: ^0.1.0+1`
on Flutter `0.11.7`

Comment: Yeah, I have the same issue, I remember when I did my test the firebase_dynamic_link was using this library:  com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:16.0.1  , but now it's updated to  api 'com.google.firebase:firebase-dynamic-links:16.1.2'  , maybe there is an issue with that version.
I'll open a new flutter issue

Comment: well I see there is an open issue about that: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/20944    @Dario lelardi , could you repo the issue on iOS? or only happens on android?

Comment: new issue opened here: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/24629

Answer (score 1):

I've already fixed the issue on my repo, could you try using this config in `pubspec.yaml`:

```
firebase_dynamic_links:
   git: 
     url: https://github.com/diegoveloper/plugins
     path: packages/firebase_dynamic_links
```

Let me know if it works

Comment: Unfortunately the bug is still there. When I originally open the app from the link, then every call to retrieveDynamicLink returns the link again.

Comment: Yes, looks like it's an issue with the current android firebase dynamic link library.

Answer (score 0):

Not a proper solution, but I noticed that adding a delay between the resume event and actually getting the dynamic link seems to solve the problem.

Might be useful as a temporary workaround.

I'm using 500ms.

Must be some kind of race condition involved.

The iOS implementation actually suffered from the same (similar) issue before:
https://medium.com/@diegoveloper/flutter-firebase-dynamic-link-6f1b79278ce0

Example code exists in the link.

But basically:

```
if (state == AppLifecycleState.resumed) {
    _timerLink = new Timer(const Duration(milliseconds: 500), () {
    _retrieveDynamicLink();
  });
}
```

EDIT: Just noticed that [@diegoveloper](https://stackoverflow.com/users/666221/diegoveloper) is the creator of both the article + workaround + the iOS fix and the new Android flutter plugin bug report.
So, thank you!